# Combine similar events on consecutive dates to a single event FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I hope you are guys are doing fine.

I am working on Full Calendar and having a kind of situation there.
I have different dates corresponding to a specific event in my database. These dates can be consecutive and discrete based on different scenarios. From the dates which I have, I create the events array and render the full calendar. and output is as follows:

[image]

As you can see that the title of the events is the same so **I want to combine them in a single event.** Is there any built-in method available to achieve targeted output?

**Example Output**

[image]

Comment: well if you literally declare them as one single event object starting on the 7th and ending on the 9th then it'll do that. (P.S. I'm guessing you got the second screenshot from the demos on the fullCalendar website? If you want to know how they work, just click View Source in your browser and take a look, everything is there including the data, or if the data is fetched via ajax in the demo you can of course watch your browser's Network tools and see the JSON returned by the call).

Comment: yes, the second screenshot is from the fullcalendar's website. so is there any method available to map my days to start and end date?

Comment: Well I don't know your exact data structure or how you code it now. But basically create one event where the start date is the date of your first day and the end date is the date of your last day. That's all there is to it.

Comment: There is not a built-in function that does what you want. You need to merge your events server side. Should be pretty easy